# Assigning a function pointer to a function inside another function

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am currently trying to make a little user prompt were a function pointer gets assigned. My problem is that I can't get the now assigned function pointer out in `main` again.
The code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

double print_2 (void);

double print_1 (void);

void promt_user_input(double (*fn)(void));

//program to test funtion pointers inside funtions

//proof of consept

int    main(void) {
  double result;
  double (*fn)(void);

  promt_user_input(fn);
  //result = *fn;
  printf("het %lf",(fn)());
  //This will not print no matter what i do.
}

void promt_user_input(double (*fn)(void)) {
  int coice;
  printf("Enter 1 or 2\n");

  scanf(" %d",&coice);

  switch(coice) {
    case 1: *(&fn) = print_1; printf("you typed 1\n"); break;
    case 2: *(&fn) = print_2; printf("you typed 2\n"); break;
    default: printf("INVALID INPUT"); break; 
  }
  printf("hi %lf\n",(fn)());
}

double print_1 (void){
  printf("This is option 1\n");
  return 1;
}

double print_2 (void){
  printf("This is option 2\n");
  return 2;
}
```

It compiles just fine, and the function is assigned correctly, because of the `printf` inside the `prompt_user_input` function prints the correct values. But outside of that function, it seems like it doesn't work. The `printf` function won't even run.

Comment: point function = printf*

Comment: If you want to clarify something in your question, please update the question rather than posting a comment.

Comment: You would need to pass a pointer-to-pointer. Probably alot simpler to create a typedef, and/or have `promt_user_input` return a function pointer.

Comment: Is this variable 'fn' being passed by reference or passed by value? If its passed by value, then in prompt_user_input you are just changing the local variable "fn" to point to a function, which then goes out of scope when prompt_user_input returns.

Comment: When you call `some_function(42)`, `42` usually doesn't change. When you call `some_function(some_integer_variable)`, `some_integer_variable` usually doesn't change. When you call `some_function(printf)`, `printf` usually doesn't change.  When you call `some_function(some_variable_of_type_pointer_to_function)`... you get the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `main()` function you define uninitialized pointer to function `fn` and you pass it (by **value**) to another function `promt_user_input` which initializes it *internally* by either `print_1` or `print_2` based on the user input...

But when the flow goes back to the `main()`, the `fn` inside `main()` remained initialized. Dereferencing it causes *undefined behavior*. In order to initialize `fn` properly, you need to pass its **address** to `promt_user_input` and of course its signature has to be updated properly (input argument should be of type **pointer to pointer** to function or make it return the function pointer, whatever you prefer).

```
#include <stdio.h>

double print_2 (void);
double print_1 (void);

void promt_user_input(double (**fn)(void));

int main(void)
{
  double result;
  double (*fn)(void);

  fn = NULL;    
  promt_user_input(&fn);

  if (fn)
  {
    printf("het %lf",(fn)());
  }

  return 0;
}

void promt_user_input(double (**fn)(void))
{
  unsigned int coice;
  int res;

  printf("Enter 1 or 2\n");

  res = scanf("%u",&coice);
  if (res != 1 || !coice || coice > 2)
  {
      printf("Invalid input!\n");
      return;
  }

  switch(coice)
  {
    case 1: *fn = print_1; printf("you typed 1\n"); break;
    case 2: *fn = print_2; printf("you typed 2\n"); break;
  }

  printf("hi %lf\n",(*fn)());
}

double print_1 (void)
{
  printf("This is option 1\n");
  return 1.0;
}

double print_2 (void)
{
  printf("This is option 2\n");
  return 2.0;
}
```

Few additional remarks:

1. You have to check for the return value of `scanf` to take care of invalid input.
2. Due to invalid input, the `fn` will remain *uninitialized* so you **must not** dereference it in such case. You need either initialize the `fn` to some invalid value and then check if it has a valid value before using it or make `promt_user_input` return a status which will indicate if the input argument was initialized successfully.
3. `double` constants must have *floating* point: 1-->`int`, 1.0 --> `double`
4. Prefer using unsigned types when negative values have no meaning (like `coice`).
5. `int main(void)` should return an `int` value at the end of the flow.

Comment: Thank you very much :D. I finally got it to work. I think it's incredible that people like you actually take time out of your day to answer a noobie like me. ;)

Comment: Alternately have `prompt_user_input` *return* the function pointer rather than taking an argument.  Arguments should be for inputs to the function; use the return value for outputs.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Right. I also mentioned it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since C is pass by value, you need to pass a pointer-to-pointer to the `promt_user_input` function:

```
int main(void)
{
    double (*fn)(void);

    promt_user_input(&fn);
    printf("het %lf",fn());
}

void promt_user_input(double (**fn)(void))
{
    int coice;
    printf("Enter 1 or 2\n");

    scanf(" %d", &coice);

    switch(coice){
        case 1: *fn = print_1; printf("you typed 1\n"); break;
        case 2: *fn = print_2; printf("you typed 2\n"); break;
        default: printf("INVALID INPUT"); break; 
    }
}
```

---

Things become easier to understand if you create a typedef:

```
typedef double (*func)(void);
void promt_user_input(func *fn);

int main(void)
{
    func fn;

    promt_user_input(&fn);
    printf("het %lf", fn());
}

void promt_user_input(func *fn)
{
    // Same as above....
```

---

Then you can avoid the pointer-to-pointer by having the function return a value:

```
typedef double (*func)(void);
func promt_user_input();

int main(void)
{
    func fn = promt_user_input();
    if (NULL != fn) {
        printf("het %lf", fn());
    }
}

func promt_user_input()
{
    int coice;
    printf("Enter 1 or 2\n");

    scanf(" %d", &coice);

    switch(coice){
        case 1:
            printf("you typed 1\n");
            return print_1;
        case 2: 
            printf("you typed 2\n");
            return print_2;
        default: 
            printf("INVALID INPUT");
            return NULL; 
    }
}
```